# Where can I find GIS dataset (.shp, .gdb, etc) on Washington DC lead pipes?

Tags: data, united-states

I keep seeing articles about DC recently publishing a map of pipes in the city. I can only find the interactive version but need it in a .shp, .gdb or some format that can be used in Arc (.txt or .csv with x,y field/a field that I can relate with a census .shp such as census code or zip code, but preferable the former). Here is one article I've seen: http://dcist.com/2016/06/dc_water_map.php

Anyone know where I can find this?

Comment: "DC Water Launches A Map That Shows If Homes Have Lead Pipes" Did you try contacting DC Water?

Comment: Hi Dan--I've looked on their website but could only find the interactive site here https://geo.dcwater.com/Lead/... I will email them today and call on Monday, but not really sure which number to call. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacted DC Water and they gave me this: https://www.dcwater.com/about/foia/WaterServiceMaterial.pdf

.pdf not the most desirable format, but after a few  hours I've converted it to excel. Now just need to geocode....

Answer (score 2):

[image]sign in at **www.arcgisonline.com**,then visit **www.arcgisonline.com/home**. Go to the search area, and type **"Washington DC Pipes**". All related data will show up, click on the drop down at open, and download the **data(.shp)**.

This is one of the  data I saw there relating to Washington, DC.